# How to backport upgrade failure correction to trusty?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

Ubuntu 14.04.5->16.04 upgrade failure due to Bug#1611470 in launchpad.

I start `do-release-upgrade` it fails due to [Bug #1611470](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1611470). The bug is fixed, however the fixed version of the release upgrader is not available in trusty.
How to backport the correction to trusty?

Update on 2016. October 15: Same error appears after applying the patch recommended by Stephen.
Here is the trackback:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4_bu5g66/xenial", line 8, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4_bu5g66/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 242, in main
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4_bu5g66/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1876, in run
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4_bu5g66/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1841, in fullUpgrade
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4_bu5g66/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1257, in doDistUpgrade
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4_bu5g66/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1062, in _enableAptCronJob
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/etc/cron.daily/apt'`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work...

1. Download [`DistUpgradeController.diff`](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/278008176/DistUpgradeController.diff) somewhere (say, `~/Downloads`)
2. From the same directory, try to apply the patch to a copy of the affected file:

   ```
   cp /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py .
   patch -p1 < DistUpgradeController.diff
   ```
3. If that doesn't produce any error, copy the fixed file into place (with a backup first):

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py{,.bak}
   sudo cp DistUpgradeController.py /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/
   ```

If all this succeeds, you'll have applied the fix for [#1611470](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1611470).

Comment: Same error appears after applying the patch:

Comment: FTR: I think the problem with this suggested is that if you use do-release-upgrade, it will download a new package with the upgrader and runs it right away. So, you'll probably apply the patch to the wrong file. To make it work, go to the directory `/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-<randomchars>` that was created during the failed run, then run `patch -p1 < DistUpgradeController.diff` to apply the patch and then run `sudo ./xenial` from that directory to make it work.